# add empty line between each time blocks

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the input log a form:

```
system 2018-02-05 04:15:49 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:52 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:53 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:20:06 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: bbbbbbbbbbbbb
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:23:49 :: bbbbbbbbbbbbb
system 2018-02-05 04:23:49 :: ccccccccccccc
```

and want to have separated each time block by empty line.
Expected output for above input would be:

```
system 2018-02-05 04:15:49 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa

system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:15:52 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:15:53 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:20:06 :: ccccccccccccc

system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: bbbbbbbbbbbbb
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc

system 2018-02-05 04:23:49 :: bbbbbbbbbbbbb
system 2018-02-05 04:23:49 :: ccccccccccccc
```

Comment: awk '{print $2,$3}' log|sort -u|while read a b;do awk -vv="$a$b" '$2$3==v' log;echo;done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to form the key that each of the lines are unique with, in your case it is `$2` and `$3` (i.e. in Awk's context second and third space delimited columns).

We build a unique key(`$2 $3`) by this combination and while parsing the lines if this combination varied from the subsequent line, we print a new line character (also represented by special variable `ORS` or just `print ""` in Awk). The below code reflects just that

```
$ awk '($2 $3)!=p && NR>1 {print ""} {print; p=($2 $3)}' file
system 2018-02-05 04:15:49 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

...
```

Comment: You can remove $2

Comment: @TigerTV.ru For this particular piece of data yes but most likely not for real data. There is always the possibility of "today 12:00:00" and "tomorrow 12:00:00".

Comment: I don't understand. What would be if there are "today 12:00:00" and "tomorrow 12:00:00"?

Comment: The case where there are 2 consecutive lines where the date (`$2`) changes but the time (`$2`) doesn't.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another short **`awk`** approach:

```
awk 'NR>1 && !a[$2$3]++{ print "" }1' file
```

- `!a[$2$3]++` - check for unique *datetime* value using concatenation of *date* `$2` and *time* `$3` values as array key

---

The output:

```
system 2018-02-05 04:15:49 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  
system 2018-02-05 04:15:51 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:15:52 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:15:53 :: aaaaaaaaaaaaa  

system 2018-02-05 04:20:06 :: ccccccccccccc

system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: bbbbbbbbbbbbb
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc
system 2018-02-05 04:21:10 :: ccccccccccccc

system 2018-02-05 04:23:49 :: bbbbbbbbbbbbb
system 2018-02-05 04:23:49 :: ccccccccccccc
```

Comment: Memory usage is growing up when it uses a big log.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, then don't use it for "big log". This is an alternative approach

Comment: I don't use, it just an addition to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another one `awk` approach for each time blocks

Set `filter` on what time interval you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

Year='$2'
Month='$2$3'
Day='$2$3$4'
Hour='$2$3$4$5'
Minute='$2$3$4$5$6'
Second='$2$3$4$5$6$7'

filter=$Second

awk -F'[ :-]' $filter'!=p{print ""}{p='$filter'}{print}' sys.log
```

https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^\(.*::\).*\n\1/!P;//!s/^[^\n]*//;P;D' file
```

Keep a two line window throughout the length of the file. If the first lines key does not match the second, print the first line and then remove its contents. Always print the next line and then delete and repeat. If the first and second lines keys do not match the first line will now be empty except for a newline.

On reflection, a shorter answer:

```
sed 'N;P;/^\(.*::\).*\n\1/D;s/^[^\n]*//;P;D' file
```

Always print the first line of a two line window. If the keys in the first and second lines differ, make an empty line before the second line, print, delete and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I have another simple solution using a bash `for` loop and `grep`. Not elegant (and I think fairly slow once the input file gets too large), but it works for the example on the question:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cut -d ' ' -f1-3 input_file.txt | sort -u)
    do 
        grep $i input_file.txt
        echo
    done
```

The `IFS` change makes sure the `for` loop reads the variables as lines, not only records (see more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces)). Then the `$i` variable stores unique values of the first 3 fields, then `grep` those back in the original file, introducing an empty line with `echo` after each iteration. I realize now that this is reading the input_file twice, but anyway, hope it helps.